# Google Apps Script - gSheet - set document properties only once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to store some settings as document properties in a google apps script. I do this onOpen(), so I basically overwrite those values everytime the doc is opened. Is there a way to do this, where the settings are set once and do not get overwritten. Maybe even a way to set document properties within the GUI?

Comment: Properties Service doesn't have a "built-in" way of making a setting immutable.  Your code could do a simple test for an existing value with that key name, and if there is an existing value, don't set it again.  If the Apps Script project were an add-on, then you could set the value from the `onInstall()` function, but a user could remove and then install an add-on multiple times.  Because `onOpen()` runs every time that the document is opened, you might look for another action that isn't used as much.  You can call the server from the HTML UI with `google.script.run.serverFunctionName()`

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) on the Google App Script Properties Service, it allows to do just that and there are several settings to tweak how they are stored and how to access them.

You could potentially check `onOpen()` whether they have or should change and update/use them as needed.